# $f(x)$ is continuous in $[0,\infty)$ and $f(0)=1 , \lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=-3$

Tags: calculus

> $f(x)$ is continuous in $[0,\infty)$ and $f(0)=1 , \lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=-3$ , Prove exist $c \in (0,\infty)$ such that $f(c)=\frac {c-1}{c+1}$

Hello everyone.
I'm posting this because I'm not sure if I proved it right and I have a feeling I assumed something wrong.. anyways my try :

We can see that $-1<\frac {c-1}{c+1}<1$ because $c \in [0,\infty)$.
since $"f(\infty)"=-3<-1<\frac {c-1}{c+1}<1=f(0)$ , we know that $\frac {c-1}{c+1}$ is between $f(0)$ and $f(\infty)$.
by Intermediate value theorem we get that exist $c\in [0,\infty)$ such that $f(c)=\frac {c-1}{c+1}$ as required.

As you can see I'm pretty sure I can't write $f(\infty)$ and there is the mistake but I don't know how to write it in different way.

Comment: Just write $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put $g(x) = f(x) - \frac{x-1}{x+1}$. Then $g$ is continuous on $(-1, \infty)$, $g(0)=2$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = -4$. In particular, there exists $B >0$ such that $g(B)<0$. Applying the intermediate value theorem to $g$, we get $c \ 
\in (0, B)$ such that $g(c)=0$.